# WiFi Speed very low after router change

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

After a router and internet speed upgrade (32 Mbps to 250 Mbps, Vodafone, Fritzbox, Germany), my Wi-Fi connection started fluctuating.
WhatsApp calls keep losing connection every few seconds and websites randomly don't load for a few seconds. I did a short Wi-Fi test (6 Minutes) and my dBm value was always above -62dBm. Download speeds were fluctuating a lot (from 4 Mbps to over 200 Mbps), but they stuck mostly at 4 Mbps. Often, to get back online on a certain app, I need to restart it.
I don't really know what I can do to fix this. I would be thankful for any help!

Comment: It is recommended you take this issue up with your ISP. They will probably be able to sort it out better than anyone else.

Comment: Also see if your current router has enough internal throughput to handle the large increase in ISP speed. The router probably needs to be upgraded.

Comment: It almost sounds to me like congestion in the WIFI spectrum - is other APs conflicting withbyours. Have you looked at the other channels in the area and tried changing yours, and/or switching to 5 gig band?

Comment: @davidgo, thanks for the tip! I feel like the 2.4G band is not working properly,as the speed goes down as soon as my device switches. But I will test it a bit more in the coming days and tweak some values!